# Transfer data between NoSQL and SQL databases on different servers

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, triggers, mern

Currently, I'm working on a MERN Web Application that'll need to communicate with a Microsft SQL Server database on a different server but on the same network.

Data will only be "transferred" from the Mongo database to the MSSQL one based on a user action. I think I can accomplish this by simply transforming the data to transfer into the appropriate format on my Express server and connecting to the MSSQL via the matching API.

On the flip side, data will be transferred from the MSSQL database to the Mongo one when a certain field is updated in a record. I think I can accomplish this with a Trigger, but I'm not exactly sure how.

Do either of these solutions sound reasonable or are there more better/industry standard methods that I should be employing. Any and all help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (in general) two ways of doing this.

1. If the data transfer needs to happen immediately, you may be able to use triggers to accomplish this, although be aware of your error handling.
2. The other option is to develop some form of worker process in your favourite scripting language and run this on a schedule. (This would be my preferred option, as my personal familiarity with triggers is fairly limited). If option 1 isn't viable, you could set your schedule to be very frequent, say once per minute or every *x* seconds, as long as a new task doesn't spawn before the previous is completed.

The broader question though, is do you *need* to have data duplicated across two different sources? The obvious pitfall with this approach is consistency, should anything fail you can end up with two data sources wildly out of sync with each other and your approach will have to account for this.